# WHERE IN (a,b,c...) or WHERE= in loop, which one usually performs better?

Tags: mysql, sql

1. We use `SELECT * FROM profile WHERE id IN (1,2,3...)` to get all results in ResultSet. It is essentially `SELECT * FROM profile WHERE id='1' OR id='2' OR id='3'...`
2. We write a loop like:
   `foreach(int id: ids) {execute(SELECT * FROM profile WHERE id='i')}`

As far as I consider, since requests sent DB takes a lot of time, we should reduce the number of times we visit DB, so the first method is better. However, I am not sure whether it's true or not in the industry and is there's a better solution. Please enlight me, thank you :)

Comment: For security reasons, you should actually use the loop, but in a PDO context.

Comment: It really depends on your use case. Generally IN() is easier to write and less overhead on the db since it's one question only. @Strawberry, it is indeed safer in a PDO context, but then securitywise it doesn't matter whether it's a loop or not.

Comment: @marekful well it’s only because of the difficulties of using IN() in prepared statements, but I see that there are some clever hacks

Comment: @Strawberry Are you conjecturing that the OP is only considering a loop because it does not know how to bind `WHERE IN`?  Because if not, your duplicate mark might not be accurate.

Comment: Hum...I don't think I am asking the same question as the link points to. Perhaps I didn't state my problem clearly, but the answer by #Tim Biegeleisen and comments by #marekful actually answered my question, thank you! My problem is more about query efficiency and DB optimization. Beyond the question's scope, I am happy to learn more about what I can do to improve it further(PDO), so big thanks to #Strawberry as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a performance point of view, I think your first query using `WHERE IN (...)` is the preferred way to go here.  As you and the comments have pointed out, calling many queries in a loop from PHP has a big overhead, because each new call to the DB takes network time among other things.  On top of this, MySQL can internally optimize a `WHERE IN` clause.  For instance, it can create a map of the `IN` values which allows for fast lookup.  In an ideal case, making a single query using `WHERE IN` might not peform much worse than searching for a single value.